# How to track installer script in a pipeline not executing?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to the whole Azure DevOps world and just got transferred to a new team that does just that.

One of my assignments is to fix an issue with a pipeline where one of the steps runs a shell script that installs an application. Currently, the step seems to run without any issue shown on the log, but when we connect to the container's pod, the app is not there.

If we run the script directly inside the pod, the application is installed correctly. I'm not sure how to track this. One of the things I've tried was to check the event log to see if there's any error while the installation is executed:`Get-Eventlog -LogNmae "Windows PowerShell" -Newest 20`, so far no luck here. Again, kinda of new at this, not sure what other tools are out there to track the reason why the script is not installing during the pipeline execution.

Comment: How is it going with this case? Does below answer help your to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to how the task was awaited. Adding this piped params helped us solve the issue:
**RUN powershell C:\dev\myprocess.ps1 -PassThru | Wait-Process;**

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot your pipeline run, you can configure your pipeline logs to be more verbose.

1, To configure verbose logs for a **single run**, you can start a new build by choosing Run pipeline and selecting Enable system diagnostics, Run.

[image]

2,To configure verbose logs for all runs, you can add a variable named system.debug and set its value to true.

You can also try logging into your agent server and check for the event log. See [this blog](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_detect_software_installations.html) for view event log on windows.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be an issue with having the docker installed inside a windows server as opposed to a windows 10 OS. The script works fine in windows 10, we might need to install some .net dependencies to be able to install apps thru docker.